# Couldn't match expected type with actual type (while i think they're both the same)

Tags: haskell

I'm currently doing a course on haskell and trying to create a simple dice game. But having a pretty hard time :). Could someone help me out with this error:

```
    * Couldn't match expected type `Tactiek'
                  with actual type `(GepakteStenen -> Worp -> IO Steen,
                                     GepakteStenen -> IO Bool)'
    * In the expression: (spelerTactiekPakken, spelerTactiekDoorgaan)
      In an equation for `spelerTactiek':
          spelerTactiek = (spelerTactiekPakken, spelerTactiekDoorgaan)
   |
40 | spelerTactiek = (spelerTactiekPakken,spelerTactiekDoorgaan)
```

---

I've defined Tactiek as follows:

```
data Tactiek = Tactiek
  {tactiekPakken    ::GepakteStenen -> Worp -> IO Steen
, tactiekDoorgaan   ::GepakteStenen -> IO Bool
 }
```

---

and getting the error in the following of my code:

```
spelerTactiekPakken :: GepakteStenen -> Worp -> IO Steen
spelerTactiekPakken w g = do putStrLn ("Worp: " ++ show w)
                             putStr "pakken? "
                             c <- getChar
                             putChar '\n'
                             if eerderGegooid c g then
                               do putStrLn "Waarde al gebruikt."
                                  spelerTactiekPakken w g
                             else 
                               if char2Steen c `elem` w then 
                                 return $ char2Steen c
                               else 
                                 do putStrLn "Geen geldige waarde gekozen."
                                    spelerTactiekPakken w g
```

Hopefully it's a little clear like this (this is my first post).

Could someone help me out!

Comment: The error mentions line 40, which contains `spelerTactiek = (spelerTactiekPakken,spelerTactiekDoorgaan)`. This isn't in the code you provided; can you show us that as well?

Comment: Didnt see that sorry. It's the following:

spelerTactiek :: Tactiek
spelerTactiek = (spelerTactiekPakken,spelerTactiekDoorgaan)

Comment: Actually, I can infer the error even without the code: You are trying to contruct a `Tactiek` using a pair rather than the `Tactiek` constructor.  Instead of `spelerTactiek = (spelerTactiekPakken,spelerTactiekDoorgaan)`, it should be `spelerTactiek = Tactiek spelerTactiekPakken spelerTactiekDoorgaan`.

Comment: Your quick, already solved now xD. Thanks very much!

Comment: tl;dr: Two types aren't equivalent just because they contain the same members.

Answer (score 3):

The type `(GepakteStenen -> Worp -> IO Steen, GepakteStenen -> IO Bool)` is not the same as the type `Tactiek`. To create a value of type `Tactiek`, you must use the `Tactiek` constructor. Fortunately, there's an easy way to get from one to the other:

```
uncurry Tactiek :: 
    ( GepakteStenen -> Worp -> IO Steen
    , GepakteStenen -> IO Bool
    ) -> Tactiek
```

so you should define `spelerTactiek` as:

```
spelerTactiek =
    uncurry Tactiek (spelerTactiekPakken, spelerTactiekDoorgaan)
```

or rather than constructing a tuple at all, just call `Tactiek` directly:

```
spelerTactiek = Tactiek spelerTactiekPakken spelerTactiekDoorgan
```